# JQuery events not firing when adding elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, zoomooz

I am using http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/ to zoom elements on my web page.

However when I am adding elements dynamically through `.append()`, the elements don't zoom.

I tired using `.on` and doing stuff manually with no success.

```
$(document).on("click", ".lot", function () {
                $(this).zoomTarget();
            });
```

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="zoomViewport">
            <div class="lotmap zoomContainer">
 </div></div>
```

Any elements added in the `div class="zoomViewport"` with data attribute `data-targetsize="0.05"` and class `zoomTarget` would be zoomed when clicked.

**Example:** `<img class="zoomTarget lot" data-targetsize="0.05" src="../images/sold.png"/>`

I am appending elements to `lotmap`.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The event is firing but I need the plugin events to  work as it used to before adding elements dynamically.

Comment: This should work, can you show a fiddle?

Comment: if you add a console.log("hi") before the zoomTarget call do you get anything? I want to be sure the click is firing

Comment: Show a complete example that you've verified fully represents the problem. Please don't just show scattered bits of code.

Comment: the click is firing. but the plugin events are not working.

Comment: Did you have to apply the plugin to the  original elements? If so, then you'll need to apply it to new ones too when you create them.

Comment: Are you attaching the event handler (click) within the document ready event?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: OP is attaching to `document`, which is always present.

Comment: @BlueSkies yes. I missed that.

Comment: The plugin used to work automatically by adding data-attribute `data-targetsize="0.05"` and class `zoomTarget`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with zoomooz. In this example you make new elements by clicking the button. After the new element is made, you just call zoomooz on it with zoomTarget():

```
    <button> Make A Box </button>

    <div class="zoomViewport">
        <div id="container" class="zoomContainer">
            <div class="box zoomTarget"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        function _calls_zoom(){
            $(".box").zoomTarget();
        }

        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#container").append("<div class='box'></div>");
            _calls_zoom();
        });

    </script>
```

Not a perfect example, but I [uploaded a working copy](http://acpote.com/code_shares/zoomoozTesting/) on my server which includes a bunch of my notes on this as well as a download link so you can grab the example and tweak it to your needs.